# Constant/issue functions must only have a non empty offset exception in sonarqube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube

when running a analysis, on client side the analysis is SUCCESSFUL. In server side it fails with

```
2015.11.21 18:58:54 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Failed to execute task AVEq-_POC3ZgM3TJ4WGx
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Constant/issue functions must only have a non empty offset
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.debt.internal.DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.validate(DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.java:88) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.debt.internal.DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.(DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.java:45) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleImpl.effectiveRemediationFunction(RuleImpl.java:124) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleImpl.(RuleImpl.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.loadRulesFromDb(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:102) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.ensureInitialized(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:91) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.findByKey(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep$IsValid.apply(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep$IsValid.apply(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:647) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:268) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:226) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:334) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep.execute(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:63) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:78) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.run(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:55) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
2015.11.21 18:58:54 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=Trimble.Connect:Desktop:master | id=AVEq-_POC3ZgM3TJ4WGx | time=721ms
```

How can i know what is the rule that is having the incorrect debt values.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figure out this by patching sonarqube to tell me what rule it was, see [commit](https://github.com/jmecosta/sonar/commit/5c78a59aa4b19f2f867a3bcde33eca906ca9a47c)

Finally i found it was related with some compiler rules from c++ plugin that were renamed to compiler specific rules and for some reason after upgrading for 5.2 those started to be evaluated against their technical characteristics.

The solution was to revert back those rules in the c++ community plugin by patching also the code of the plugin

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with 5.4 and like you, I cannot see the issues. Can you give the link to the commit of the C++ plugin which fixes the issue for you?

Comment: Thought in 5.4 they would already improve this, best advise is to patch sonar source and check what is the rule. As far as I know it can ve anything even custom rules

Comment: Well, it appears that my problem was unrelated (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/7b1glPCyb3o)...)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with SonarQube 5.4.  I was able to correct it by executing the following query against the sonar database.

```
DELETE from sonar.rules where status = 'REMOVED'
```

I assume this might change debt calculated for old projects.